# how to show tabbar controller into next View

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a TabBar Controller in AppDelegate and then Navigation Controller on TabBar. But i get problem when i push Navigation Controller to other View Controller while remaining on first tabItem of TabBar.

My AppDelegate.h is:

```
 @interface IlmStreamAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate> 
    {
        UIWindow *window;
        UITabBarController *rootViewController;
        UINavigationController *_navController;
    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *rootViewController;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navController;

    @end
```

My AppDelegate.m is:

```
  #import "IlmStreamAppDelegate.h"

    @implementation IlmStreamAppDelegate

    @synthesize window;
    @synthesize rootViewController;
    @synthesize navController;
    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Application lifecycle

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        [rootViewController setTitle:@"Categories"];    
        _navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
        [window  addSubview:_navController.view];

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        return YES;
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write write a custom XXTabBarController (plain subclass of UIViewController) that can be pushed onto a nav controller stack, but still have all the functionality of "view controller. Each "tab" has its own view controller.

Comment: Thanks all! I have done with it,by using UINavigationController for each item of TabBarController.

Comment: Thanks rishi, but i think it takes more than 15 reutations to moke a vote-up. By the way i care about all answers given to me, and i check them. If it works then i always thanks and in the other case i comments and explain my problem in more detail.

Comment: what the issue if someone gave you write answer and his reputation also increases for that..there is no harm in that..